# Determine RAID configuration XenServer HP Server ML370 G5

Tags: raid, hp, xenserver, hp-proliant

I use a HP ProLiant ml370G5 server. Its OS is XenServer from Citrix.(based on Xen).

Last week one its hard disks has been damaged and I want to change it.

I want to know what is its RAID configuration (for example RAID 1 or 2 or ...). How I can determine what is its RAIF configuration and how I can change it if I want?

Comment: You can tell us the number of hard drives in the setup, and we can guess, or, you can go here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Standard_levels and guess, or, you can access your RAID controller on the server and see which setup it uses.

Comment: Did this solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Most RAIDs have an option to go into the setup utility right after you power the machine on. It will say "Press Ctrl-R Now" or Ctrl-*Any Letter*.

If you have the HP SmartStart CD that came with the server you can boot to that and it will have a RAID config utility on it.

You can get [SmartStart](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=344318&taskId=135&prodTypeId=18964&prodSeriesId=345557&lang=en&cc=us) here. Doesnt matter which OS you choose because they are all the same.

[Heres](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00729544/c00729544.pdf) a PDF all about HP arrays

But if its a hotswap RAID then just pull out the bad one and put the new one in. It will regenerate on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the hard drive if you have a spare or replacement available. A spare part number is available on the drive's label. The ML370 G5 is possibly out of standard warranty (3 years) at this point, so you may have to purchase a replacement. The part number on the disk will help there.

You can download and install the [HP Management agents for XenServer](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3279719&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=1121474&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4039), which would give you greater insight into hardware health going forward. In the meantime, you *could* reboot and enter the BIOS raid configuration utility (press `F8` when prompted) to see the Array Controller Configuration. However, depending on the array health, that may not be a good idea.

How did you identify this problem? HP drives will show a solid amber or red light upon failure. A flashing amber/red light indicates a disk pre-failure. What do the LEDs on the disks look like, and how many drives are present in the system? That will help us understand what's going on.

Comment: It's Red.
it have 8, 72 GB Hard disk.

Comment: I would suggest replacing the disk with the correct replacement part. Is this XenServer 4 or XenServer 5?

Comment: It seems that, Server Use raid 1 configuration. Because when I use XenCenter to manage it, it show has 293 GB free space.(it has total 576 GB )

Comment: It is XenServer 5.6

Comment: 8 x 72GB disks in RAID 1+0 == 288GB usable space.